# MomentJS Date to java.sql.timestamp

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, date, momentjs

I use a React component to get some date values.
My backend is write in Scala and only want java.sql.Timestamp date format.

Juste before POST my entites, I have to transforme my date from momentjs object to java.sql.Timestamp.

I tried moment.unix(), moment.valueOf(), but nothing seems good.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try `moment.unix()*1000`

Comment: Really hard to give you a good answer, [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) or [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) should do what you need. Why are they not good for you?

Comment: "*…but nothing seems good*" is not a sufficient description of your problem. Why isn't *unix* or *valueOf* "good"?